# Redirect customPost url to another url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, litespeed

Trying to redirect customPost tag url to `/shop` page, but everything I have tried was failed, any idea?

1st try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/collection_tag/(.*) /shop
```

2nd try:

```
RewriteRule ^/collection_tag/(.*)/ /shop [R=301,L]
```

Sample url is

> `https://example.com/collection_tag/blah-blah/`

But after reloading this page, still show same page, not redirect to `/shop`

Here is full `htaccess` content

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteRule ^collection_tag/(.*)/ /shop [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: When you configure mod_rewrite via .htaccess, the path RewriteRule matches against never starts with a slash, that has been stripped off at this point already. Try `RewriteRule ^collection_tag/(.*)/ /shop [R=301,L]`, and make sure you put it before the general WordPress rewrites.

Comment: @CBroe `RewriteRule ^collection_tag/(.*)/ /shop [R=301,L]` still return same, I tried without slash before. and I put it before wordpress rewrite.

Comment: Show the full rewrite configuration then, please, and also an example URL.

Comment: Could it be that your rule does not get applied at all? Where did you implement that rule and how did you verify that it gets evaluated at all?

Comment: @arkascha I tried with two ways, first, edited `htaccess` manually from `ftp` second, installed a plugin for this, `wp-htaccess-editor` I'm not sure, I think it not read my htaccess at all, because I rename htaccess file , but nothign changed on site, like 404 or etc..

Comment: That is what I thought. Check if you have enabled the interpretation of such distributed configuration files _at all_ (or: how did you enable that?). Also how they should be named, this can also be configured in your http server.

Comment: @arkascha I'm using litespeed server, and pretty sure rewrite is enabled `
rewrite  {
  enable                  1
  autoLoadHtaccess        1
}` confused, I don't know what's happened, but if not read htaccess at all, site should return 404 for such url site.com/post/22, right?

Comment: Implement a syntax error into your configuration file, monitor the http server's error log file and make a test request. Do you get any error or is the issue ignored?

Comment: And also check if the behavior changes if you replace the `L` flag in your collection_tag rewrite rule with the `END` flag. You might experience an issue with your rewritten request getting rewritten again ...

Answer (score 0):

OpenLiteSpeed supports Rewriterule only, so "RedirectMatch" may not work.

Try the following rule, it should work, basically, it combines your solutions 1 and 2.

```
RewriteRule ^/collection_tag/(.*) /shop [R=301,L]
```

If you are using openlitespeed web server, please restart it to load the rule.

```
systemctl restart lsws
```

Comment: The regex has an erroneous `*` at the end (so it only matches "/collection_tag" or "/collection_tag/") - this should either be `.*` or omitted altogether. But since this is in `.htaccess`, the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ does not start with a slash - or is this different on OLS?

Comment: Both * and .* works, let me update my reply. The main different part is to remove the slash after that.

Comment: "Both * and .* works" - A stray `*` at the end would _not_ have worked (ie. `/*`) since it wouldn't have matched the example URL given in the question: `/collection_tag/blah-blah/`.